# Serialize empty List by ignoring null element/property in fasterXml Jackson java

Tags: java, json, xml, jackson, fasterxml

When I am trying to serialize a class, Jackson giving empty list as list with one empty element.

```
....
@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "users")
@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "user")
private List<User> users;
....
```

Xml Output:

```
<response>
   <users>
        <user/>
   </users>
</response>
```

Json Output:

```
{
    "users": null
}
```

But I think, I should get empty list as below (without empty user element inside users):

```
<response>
   <users/>
</response>
```

How to fix this ?

Comment: have you initialized `List<Users> users` somewhere?

Comment: @ShanuGupta No.

Comment: You should initialize it at someplace (in constructor?).

Comment: @ShanuGupta I cant. its JPA entity object and its OneToMany mapping, so by default lazy fetch its NULL only

Answer (score 0):

Just returning empty list from `getUsers()` gives desired result.

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "response")
public class Response {

    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "users")
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "user")
    private List<User> users;

    public List<User> getUsers() {

        if(null == users) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }
}
```

**Main Method**

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
Response response = new Response();
String s = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(response);
System.out.println(s);

response.setUsers(Arrays.asList(new User("1", "Hemant")));
s = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(response);
System.out.println(s);
```

**Output**

```
<response>
  <users/>
</response>

<response>
  <users>
    <user>
      <id>1</id>
      <name>Hemant</name>
    </user>
  </users>
</response>
```

One more thing, when `getUsers()` is unchanged

```
public List<User> getUsers() {  
    /*if(null == users) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }*/
    return users;
}
```

**Output is**

```
<response/>
```

Comment: with normal java classes its working fine but with mappings not working i.e., OneToMany(mappedBy = "query")

Answer (score 0):

If you use the same model for `Hibernate/DB` and `Jackson/XML` you need to load appropriate Hibernate module to properly serialize persisted collections. For more information see [jackson-datatype-hibernate](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-hibernate).